Can some sentences be independently written without finite verb?
"Following the arrival of western powers such as the Spanish, the British, the Dutch, French, Germans, the Sultan thalassocracy and sovereign political powers were relinquished by 1915 through an agreement that was signed with the United States.[17][18][19][20] In the second half of the 20th century, Filipino government never official recognition of the head of the royal house of the sultanate."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultanate_of_Sulu
This is excerpt from Wikipedia. The sentence in bold has no verb but it has been written as independent sentence.
Is it right to write a independent sentence without finite verb?

It looks like a mistake, perhaps the author omitted a word like "gave (official recognition)" or the sentence should be rephrased.

This sentence is wrong in many ways. "... never GAVE official recognition TO the head ..." or more simply "... never officially recognised the head ..." would fix it grammatically, and I assume would also give the intended meaning. This sentence has become completely garbled somehow or been written by a non-native speaker. As the rest of the article seems to be competently written I would put this down to a bad edit.
And no, you need a verb for a complete sentence, what you have here is a string of noun phrases thrown on a page, with the way they relate to each other needing to be inferred.

No. This is never correct except for brief informal utterances like "Too late!".
The sentence doesn't work. It should read "The Filipino government never officially recognised or gave official recognition to the head of the royal house..."
